# Limit inside a series

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(b_q)$ and $(a_{n,q})$ be two sequences (with not necessarily positive members) such that $$\left|\sum_{q\geq 1}b_q\right|<\infty,\quad \left|\sum_{q\geq 1}b_qa_{n,q}\right|<\infty,\forall n,\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{q\geq 1}|a_{n,q}|=0.$$
Does it follow then that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{q\geq 1}b_qa_{n,q}=0$$
? If not, a counterexample would be nice.

Comment: what is the sense of $\sum b_n<\infty$ if $b_n$ is not supposed to be positive?

Comment: Consider $b_q = (-1)^{q+1}/\sqrt{q}$.

Comment: @mookid: sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: @DanielFischer: what is your suggestion for the $a$ sequence?

Comment: For example $(-1)^{q+1}/\sqrt{q}$ for $n \leqslant q \leqslant 3n$, $0$ otherwise.

Comment: If you have $\sum \lvert b_q\rvert < \infty$, things change (dominated convergence theorem).

Comment: @DanielFischer: I wish I had $\sum|b_q|<\infty$. But I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_q$ be a conditionally convergent series such as $(-1)^q/q$.  It's known that you can choose the signs $\sigma(q)=\pm1$ to make $\sum\sigma(q)b_q$ sum to anything you want.  In particular, for any $n$, there are signs $\sigma_n(q)=\pm1$ so that $\sum\sigma_n(q)b_q=n$.

Now let $a_{n,q}=\sigma_n(q)/n$.  This is your counterexample.